# Adding one to many relationship in Django models

Tags: python, django, model, one-to-many

I have two models in my Django-REST application.

a `ProjectRequest` and a `ContactRequest`

I want to make it so, each `Projectrequest contains a list of the refered Contactrequests.`

```
class ProjectRequest(models.Model):
project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
#make array of technologiestechnologies = models.ArrayField(base_field=) (blank=True)
project_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
project_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
budget_estimation = models.IntegerField(
    default=1000,
    validators=[
    MinValueValidator(1800),
    MaxValueValidator(5000000)
])
#time_estimation = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)


class ContactRequest(models.Model):
topic = models.CharField(max_length=30)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
time = models.CharField(max_length=15)
project_request = models.ForeignKey(ProjectRequest, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

so far I have established a relationship, with a foreign key, which works fine as of now. However I want to extends the functionality, so, that the ProjectRequest contains a list of all the projectrequest. I have tried with several different fields, without any luck, and the documentation I can only find fields for `ManyToMany` and `OneToOne`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: are you using Django Rest Framework?

Comment: yes i am, but i don't think it will change the model structure?

Comment: `ProjectRequest contains a list of all the projectrequest` or `ProjectRequest contains a list of all the contactrequest` :) ?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.. `ProjectRequest contains a list of all the contactrequest`

Comment: a foreign key _is_ the correct way to do a one-to-many relationship. However, I think you may want to pass a `related_name` to your foreign key field, example `project_request = models.ForeignKey(ProjectRequest, related_name="contacts")` (don't forget to add a migration after making this edit) - and then you can access all related contact requests from the project request using `ProjectRequest.objects.get(project_name="something").contacts.all()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to achive what you want. For that, lets add a [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in model named `contact_requests`:

```
project_request = models.ForeignKey(ProjectRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contact_requests")
```

Now you can use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) to show Primary Keys of the `ContactRequest` attached to each `ProjectRequest`.

```
class ProjectRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_requests = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectRequest
        fields = ('contact_requests', 'company_name', ...)  # other fields
```

Or if you want all the values of each `contact_requests`, then you can use [nested relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) like this:

```
class ProjectRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_requests = ContactRequestSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectRequest
        fields = ('contact_requests', 'company_name', ...) # and so on
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add a property function to the ProjectRequest class that retruns all the ContactRequests that are related to that ProjectRequest like so...

```
class ProjectRequest(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #make array of technologiestechnologies = models.ArrayField(base_field=) (blank=True)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    budget_estimation = models.IntegerField(
        default=1000,
        validators=[
        MinValueValidator(1800),
        MaxValueValidator(5000000)
    ])
    #time_estimation = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def contact_requests(self):
        return ContactRequest.objects.filter(project_request=self)


class ContactRequest(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    project_request = models.ForeignKey(ProjectRequest, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I will give you an upvote, for the answer, but i think the better way, is the add the class into the serializer, like suggested above :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. This is how I solved it:

```
ContactRequest= models.ManyToManyField(ContactRequest,related_name="+")
```